# GCP/Django - Server cannot serve a simple htmlresponse

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

So while I've successfully got the django app to serve locally and use the GCP SQL as backend, after I deploy the main app I'm having a hard time getting any successful request responses using Google App Engine (Standard). Even a simple htmlresponse message doesn't work. Any advice here?

Some odd things to note: there are 500 requests about the "favicon.ico" even though I don't use an ico file but a png. Removing the use of the favicon entirely yields similar results but now says "GET / HTTP/1.1 500" (Don't know what this is about)

views.py (abbreviated)

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Congratulations!")
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python39

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "mystoragebucket"
  APPENGINE_URL: https://my-project-123456789101.uk.r.appspot.com/

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

settings.py  (abbreviated)

```
DEBUG=False
APPENGINE_URL = os.getenv('APPENGINE_URL')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [APPENGINE_URL[8:]]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [APPENGINE_URL]
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    
STATIC_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mypublicstaticbucket/static/"
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-randomstringhere'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '/cloud_sql/my-project-123456789101:us-east4:MYSQLInstanceNameHere',
        'PORT' : 5432,
        'NAME': 'MyDBNameHere',
        'USER': 'myUsername',
        'PASSWORD': 'MyPassword',
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enable logging to get details about the error.

Comment: Are you using `basic_scaling` or `automatic_scaling`? Also, did you set up `warmup_requests` or `min_idle_instances`? When you start an instance of a basic scaling service, App Engine allows it to accept traffic, but the `/.*` request is not sent to an instance until it receives its first user request. Check: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed.